# Showing a div hidden by default

Tags: toggle

I have a script that shows/hides a div.  This is the code:

```
 $('#container2').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

/* Toggle */
$('.bar-toggle').on('click',function(){

   //localstorage values are always strings (no booleans)  

   if (localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle" ) {
      $('#container2').toggleClass("with_toggle", true );
      localStorage.toggled = "with_toggle";
   } else {
      $('#container2').toggleClass("with_toggle", false );
      localStorage.toggled = "";
   }

});
```

I want to hide the div by default.  How can i modify it?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several answers, as your question is under-specified.  Since you included local storage in the first place, I am going to assume that the `with_toggle` class will cause your div to be shown and that you simply need to apply your default toggled value (null) correctly.

```
function applyToggle() {
    // JS uses "truthy" booleans - "" and null will be interpreted as false,
    // and "with_toggle" will be interpreted as true.
    $('#container2').toggleClass("with_toggle", localStorage.getItem('toggled'));
}
applyToggle();

/* Toggle */
$('.bar-toggle').on('click', function() {
    //localstorage values are always strings (no booleans)
    localStorage.setItem('toggled', localStorage.getItem('toggled') ? "" : "with_toggle");
    applyToggle();
});
```

Generally speaking, it is a good idea to separate your model (data) from your view (rendering), as I did above.  Spaghetti is hard to maintain.

Comment: Now it is hidden by default but it doesn't save when i toggle back on , i want it to be toggled off by default and if someone wanted the div to always show he can click the button and it will always show until you click de button again

Comment: You were using the read-only window.localStorage object incorrectly and I had copied and pasted that portion of your question.  I've corrected it now, above.

Comment: It still doesn't save the preference , when i refresh the div is still hidden , even tough i clicked it to be visible

Comment: Can you look inside the localStorage object with the Chrome debugger?  applyToggle() is using getItem(), so setItem() must have done the right thing if the click worked at all.  For some reason, when you refresh the page you aren't finding the same localStorage object again.  What is your context?  Has localStorage been aliased to something other than window.localStorage?

Comment: I want the element to be toggled off by default but if someone wants to activate it he can click a button and stay active until the button is clicked again , but now the element is toggled off by default but when i click the button the element activates but when i refresh , the element is toggled off again

Comment: Like I said, you need to look at your localStorage object.  Is it really window.localStorage or did you shadow it?